# PM2 Logrotate does'nt turn every days - configuration

Tags: node.js, pm2, pm2-logrotate

My node application is currently using pm2 for console logging, I need to create a logger that logs warnings and errors only and saves the logs to a log file. It should rotate interval and restarts every day of 01h00. This is my current pm2 config:

```
 "max_size": "50M",
 "compress": true,
 "rotateInterval": "* * 1 * * *"
```

This configuration does not rotate every day.

What i missed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your crontab is wrong, it should be:

```
  ...
 "rotateInterval": "0 1 * * *"
  ...
```

You can check https://crontab.guru to try/debug your crontab.

Comment: And yet I had tested that too: "0 23 * * *" hoping that the rotate rotates every 23:00.
But it didn't work.
This proposal is almost identical to what you are proposing.